# Why does Thor entrust The Collector with the Aether/Reality Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

Is there a particular reason that Thor/Asgard entrusted the Collector with the Reality Stone (Aether) in *Thor: The Dark World*?

Besides the stated reason of having two stones together, but why with *The Collector* and not someone else?

Is it because they (Asgardians) feel he'd have the means to defend himself against anybody coming to retrieve it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### **Hiding in plain sight**

The Collector a.k.a [Taneleer Tivan](https://www.marvel.com/characters/collector-taneleer-tivan) can be seen in MCU and he is actually a much more powerful being originally in comics than portrayed in the MCU

> "I present to you, Taneleer Tivan, the Collector!" ―Carina (in Guardians of the Galaxy)

[MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Collector) explains about collector as follows,

> Taneleer Tivan, also known as the Collector, is the keeper of the
>   largest collection of interstellar fauna, relics and species in the
>   galaxy, operating from the Knowhere port installation. Through his
>   dealings with Asgardians and the Guardians of the Galaxy, he was in
>   possession of one of the Infinity Stones and was nearly able to obtain
>   a second stone. However, this caused Thanos to attack his museum
>   seeking the Aether.

it further explains how Tivan got the stone in the first place,

> In 2013, two Asgardians, Sif and Volstagg, arrived at Tivan's museum,
>   bringing with them the Infinity Stone known as the Aether, which had
>   been recovered by Thor after his battle against Malekith on Earth.
>   They gave it to him believing that it would be safe from other
>   parties. When Tivan asked why they did not keep the Aether in their
>   own vault on Asgard, they explained that they thought it would not be
>   wise to keep it on Asgard since another stone, the Tesseract, was
>   already on there; a notion that Tivan agreed with.  As Sif and
>   Volstagg left the Aether in Tivan's care, Tivan remarked to his
>   assistant, Carina, that they now had one of the Infinity Stones in
>   their possession, and only needed the remaining five, hinting that
>   Tivan was already seeking the Infinity Stones. Tivan learned the
>   location  Power Stone, which was contained inside the Orb and begun
>   working out a plan to obtain it for himself.

From an [answer for a similar question in SciFi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/87962/83506) ,

> MCU version of Tivan portrays him as just an
>   eccentric collector so far, the comics version has a personal mission
>   of collecting artifacts and subjects and keeping them safe so that the
>   Universe could be repopulated. Not only does Tivan have a personal
>   mission to keep all of these artifacts safe, he also has ten heavily
>   guarded museum worlds, as well as a ship that remains in hyperspace
>   almost all of the time to avoid being detected. Additionally, he has
>   "temporal assimilator" which can be used for limited time-travel.

There was a conversation between Thor and Star-Lord in Avengers Infinity War,

> Star-Lord: "If it's with the Collector, then it's not safe. Only an
>   idiot would give that man a stone."
>
> Thor: "Or a genius."

POV from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/8toqwm/mcu_the_reason_the_asgardians_gave_the_reality/e195uus/)

> In MCU The Collector was a known buffoon - despite his reputable
>   collection of things, he was a joke across the galaxy. But then the
>   Asgardians realized that the one place nobody ever thought they'd keep
>   the reality stone was with a well-known doofus.
>
> It's essentially the galactic version of hiding something in plain
>   sight, like stealing the Mona Lisa and hanging it a small town
>   community art museum, nobody would ever think something so valuable
>   would be in such a non-descript place with such an idiot guarding it
>   that they wouldn't even bother to look there in the first place.

I found another POV in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/8toqwm/mcu_the_reason_the_asgardians_gave_the_reality/),

> Personally, I felt the most important reason was that The Collection
>   had no intention of using it. Odin/Loki didn't trust having two
>   infinity stones on Asgard, so he probably wouldn't trust the Nova Corp
>   with it either, nor the Avengers, since Earth had two already.
>
> So, Collector can be choosen for
>
> 1. Has the ability to protect a stone,
> 2. Would be willing to have a stone, despite it potentially putting a
>      bullseye on them.
> 3. Can be trusted not to abuse it.
>
> The Collector wants it for its rarity and collectability, not the
>   things he could do with it. He wasn't going to go try take over the
>   galaxy with reality warping power. So, he was a good choice. The only
>   question was his ability to safeguard it. Assuming no-one would find
>   out he'd been entrusted with it, and that the Collector had probably
>   collected a number of defence systems to protect his collection, he
>   was probably a decent enough choice.

Comment: "I present to you, Taneleer Tivan, the Collector!", what does this show about his powers ?Its just an introduction.

Comment: **That was indeed intended as an introduction.**...  *this answer is wrong on so many levels*, can you ellaborate? so I can correct 'em?

Comment: your MonaLisa reference for example, the Collector was not underqualified, but he was the right choice none the less as noone could understand the ancient entities(stones) better in the current MCU.

Comment: +1 I think the final Reddit POV explains well the unusual qualities of the Collector, which make him a defensible choice for looking after the Stone.

Comment: @masterArSuKa I'm still waiting for your kind explanation on *Man, this answer is wrong on so many levels !*, I'm always open to suggestions and willing to correct anything from me if I'm wrong. Mona Lisa reference have no reference on saying he is *underqualified*, it just explains **hiding in plain sight** with real world example. I agree it's not the best one,but for the time being.... You're welcome to add/fix/improve if you see a way

Comment: @EleventhDoctor along with what Thor said to Star Lord..

Comment: That first link just links to marvel.com, not the specific character page.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the collector was considered a joke across the galaxy? Or did you just copy __[this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/8toqwm/mcu_the_reason_the_asgardians_gave_the_reality/e195uus/)__ (or are you that user)? - Giving an Infinity Stone to an idiot is arguably more dangerous than keeping it relatively securily with another (he could lose it, sell it, trade it, use it accidentally, use it on purpose, brag to everyone about having it, ...)

Comment: @Oliver_C I think we covered almost all of the things in your list would not possibly happen with the collecter, since his main focus in life is to collect and safely store things, but the last thing, *that he actually did*.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb updated the link. thanks for noticing

Comment: @Vishwa - Yes, the Collector wouldn't do those things because he is __not__ an idiot. And since the crux of your "hiding in plain sight" argument is that he is known as an idiot/buffoon/joke across the galaxy you should support that claim with some evidence. And again, __[unless this is you](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/8toqwm/mcu_the_reason_the_asgardians_gave_the_reality/e195uus/), you shouldn't copy & paste that person's answer without giving credit__.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you just copied two paragraphs from the link pointed out by Oliver. Can you edit your post and give attribution to the author? Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Exchange and it's always [nice to give credit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where credit is due.

Comment: @AJ and Oliver_C. yes, it's from reddit. sorry I missed that. had no intention on steal that and present it as my own.

Answer (score 15):

The Collector is not a complete idiot as Quill said. He is obsessed with collecting missing and valuable artifacts at any cost. He even offers 4 billion credits for the Power Stone which startles Rocket. Therefore, it is clear that there is no other thing he would trade an infinity stone for. So, Asgardians believed that the stone won't be transferred to anyone.

Besides this, we have seen his museum where he had strong vaults and defending means, which is why he has been capable of keeping all those artifacts safe for a long time. This could also be the reason why Asgardians trusted him.

Comment: And of course the main reason they needed to entrust it with anyone else at all is because they didn't want two infinity stones kept in the same place. They probably had few other options with whom the could entrust one.

Answer (score 14):

Thor/Asgard entrusted the Collector with the Reality Stone **he would neither sell it nor use it**.

---

**He would not sell it**

The collector started collecting things as a hobby to maintain his own sanity. He eventually began to collect things just for the sake of it. He was collecting for many years. All the things he collected remained with him. He did not intend to sell them.

**He will not use it**

For thousands of years the Asgardians know him and he has not tried to dominate the world during the time. Though he says

> One down. Five to go!

in the movies I suspect he told that about collecting 5 more stones and not about using them.

**Safety**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collector_(comics)),

> Taneleer Tivan is one of the Elders of the Universe and is close to
>   his fellow Elder En Dwi Gast (the Grandmaster). He apparently came to
>   self-awareness billions of years ago, on the planet Cygnus X-1. He is
>   an enormously powerful being who wielded the Power Primordial and,
>   though at first he took the appearance of an old human, his true form
>   is a powerful alien

So he is powerful life form and was able to safeguard his collection of rare objects for thousands of years. He might be able to safeguard ether too.

They might / might not have thought he was able to defend against Thanos or Ronan or others. But they definitely believed that he will not use the stone which was far more important.

Comment: "He is an **enormously powerful being who wielded the Power Primordial** and, though at first he **took the appearance of an old human**, his true form is a powerful alien" -> this is what MCU could/should have considered... Then an epic battle would have enfolded, instead of a meekly Jar Jar Binks being slapped and stolen from his precious toy by a wanna-be-Sauron.

Comment: Thanks for saying this better than I would have, they don't trust him, but they do understand him and his motivations

Answer (score 3):

The end credit scene of *Thor:The Dark World* was made as a connection to *The Guardians of the Galaxy* which was to be released the next summer.
The Collector was supposed to have a glimpse here for Marvel fans to know him and then see him in a bigger role in the GOTG movie.

It was obvious that Asgardians couldn't store 2 infinity stones together because they were unaware of any consequences that may happen, they decided to give it to the collector only because he is a very old entity himself, he has seen and collected NUMEROUS things over the VAST time he has lived, and they knew he knows about all the weird/unknown stuff better than anyone.

Every elder has a **power primordial**, which he inherits due to the power passed on from the Big-Bang ,they have become skilled and masters of their skills over billion and billions of years.

Asgardians(even Odin) knew the experience theCollector has regarding any object new or old or ancient.
So, the Aether was handed over to him.However the Collector himself became greedy upon having a stone.

He himself says "one down....5 to go !"

Comment: You can't have a collection unless you have all of something. If you don't have any, you spend your resources completing the collections you do have. Once he obtained 1, he had to have all to complete the collection.

Comment: I never said he was called the Collector due to a collection of infinity stones lol !

Comment: True, but his name/title implies his character.  My comment was meant to support your theory that he was collecting for collecting and not using.  It is also fun to note that he did not share the sentiment of the Asgardians, that they should be kept apart.  It could also be noted that by them giving it to him, he knew where the Teseract was.

Comment: all good, cool !