# Is Comic Book Guy's Treehouse of Horror alter ego based off the Marvel franchise?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-simpsons

In [The Simpson Treehouse of Horror X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_X), Comic Book Guy has the alter ego called The Collector. The plot is that he kidnaps sci-fi/fantasy characters and preserves them.

From the hot network questions, I see that The Collector is also a Marvel character ([Why does Thor entrust the Aether/Reality Stone with The Collector?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93386/why-does-thor-entrust-the-aether-reality-stone-with-the-collector)).

My question is, **did one franchise inspire the other, or are the character similarities a coincidence?**

Answer (score 2):

Nothing suggests it's not. Both have same name and same habits, as you said for Simpsons:

> The plot is that he kidnaps sci-fi/fantasy characters and preserves them.

That's what The Collector do, collecting stuff for his [Museum](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Collector%27s_Museum) and in comics version he did collect superheroes too for his collection:

[image]

(Image source: [marvel.wikia.com](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/File:Taneleer_Tivan_(Earth-616)_from_Avengers_Vol_1_28_0001.jpg))

But in MCU he didn't try to collect superheroes yet.